# C# - Iterating through capitalized chars in a string to make sure they are equal to one of three letters not working

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement

This is what I am trying to do!

1. Obtain user input.
2. Make user input uppercase by using the .ToUpper(); method.
3. Iterate through each char of the user-inputted string and compare it to make sure it's either 'U', 'D', or 'F'. *If true, prompt user to re-enter their input. Else, continue the loop until finished.*
4. When the loop is finished, return userInput.

My code ends by calling takeUserInput();. The only input that bypasses this is by pressing enter. I think this is because I haven't programmed logic for a null input.

Thanks!

```cs
static string takeUserInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your path!\nU = One step down.\nD = One step up.\nF = One " +
    "step forward.");

    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    
    userInput = userInput.ToUpper();

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
    {
        if (userInput[i] != 'U' || userInput[i] != 'D' || userInput[i] != 'F')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only enter U, D, or F!");
            
            takeUserInput(); //Code ends here by calling takeUserInput(); 
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return userInput;
}
```

Comment: Consider transforming the recursion to an iteration, i.e. in your for loop only set a flag whether the input is acceptable or not and wrap the whole thing in a while loop that is left only if it is.

Comment: Think for a moment. If `userInput[i] != 'U'` is false, what is guaranteed to happen in the next part of your expression, `userInput[i] != 'D'`?

Comment: `if (x != 'U' || x != 'D' || x != 'F')` Can you think of an `x` where this is *not* true?

Comment: Consider something like `"UDF".Contains(userInput)`. It will be true if your input is one of U, D or F.

Comment: @dxiv to make the expression not true, x has to be either U, D, or F. I'm assuming I'm wrong.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it should check to see if the char is D, if not, then F. This is my current assumption. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Deanjvande For that you need `&&` not `||`.

Comment: @dxiv I thought I tried that. I must have had something else incorrectly written then too because that was not working for me either. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Contains` method.

```
using System;
namespace colorchange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            takeUserInput();
        }
        static string takeUserInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your path!\nU = One step down.\nD = One step up.\nF = One " +
            "step forward.");

            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            userInput = userInput.ToUpper();

            if (userInput.Contains("D") || userInput.Contains("U") || userInput.Contains("F"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You may only enter U, D, or F!");
                takeUserInput(); //Code ends here by calling takeUserInput(); 
            }
            return userInput;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is making sure user input is ONLY U, D or F (not a combination of them) you can consider this:

```
static string TakeUserInput()
{
    bool inputIsValid = false;

    while (!inputIsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your path!\nU = One step down.\nD = One step up.\nF = One step forward.");

        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        var validInputs = "udf";

        if (userInput.Length == 1 && validInputs.Contains(userInput, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            inputIsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only enter U, D, or F!");
        }
    }

    return userInput;
}
```